# How to use idoubs with Wi-fi alone in iPad? (with out telecom service)

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I found idoubs API to make video call but I'm afraid whether idoubs can be used only for telecom service. Can we use idoubs to make video call using Wi-fi feature alone? , I mean i don't want to use a SIM to contact, is it possible?